# Firefox addon submission gives error unable to contact server

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I built my first forefox addon and trying to submit it but when I try to submit if gives an error

```
Your add-on failed validation with 1 error.
There was a problem contacting the server.
```

It doesnt give any other error or warning. What does the above error mean. Did any one else face this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a temporary outage. Or your add-on really crashes the validator.
Having said this, SO isn't really the AMO support forum...

Better suited places would be [the AMO forums](https://forums.mozilla.org/addons/), the AMO editors mailing list `amo-editors@mozilla.org` or the `#amo` and/or `#addons` IRC channels on `irc.mozilla.org`.

You may also run the [validator](https://github.com/mozilla/amo-validator/) locally if you're adventurous, but the correct setup of the tool can be quite a hurdle...